# Dynamically switch bootstrap nav-tabs .active class with special dom

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom

Trying to solve a basic JS DOM-accession problem due to some special structure in my nav-tabs structure.

Based on a working fiddle I just made: https://jsfiddle.net/d5fnswwa/

How should I process to switch dynamically the .active class from a tab to another with this 'revert' HTML structure (a tags outside li tags instead of the other way around) such as:

```
<a href="#red" data-toggle="tab"><li class="active">Red</li></a>
<a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab"><li >Orange</li></a>
<a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab"><li >Yellow</li></a>
<a href="#green" data-toggle="tab"><li >Green</li></a>
<a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab"><li >Blue</li></a>
```

instead of the actual:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
<li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
<li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
<li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: Because a big part of the application has been written that way for the purpose of high-end styling each <li> inside globally cliackable and invisible a tags.

Comment: putting a tags outside of li tags is not valid html and a bad practice on top of it

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip.